# How much steel does the campaign yield in For Honor

Tags: for-honor

I've recently finished the campaign in For Honor, and noticed a few games later that I had a lot of steel.

I finished the campaign on Normal, so according to what I found online I should have gotten 4000steel.
However I also found some speculation that you are able to receive steel multiple times for the multiple difficulties.
And that there might be differing amounts of steel for each difficulty.

Is there an official source or does someone have experience with finishing the game multiple times that could tell me whether or not you receive steel multiple times?

Answer (score -2):

Off of my personal experience you receive more steel playing the hardest difficulty.

But you don’t get the hud showing where they are going to hit which makes going up against Apollyon is a pain because she seems to block about 90% of your attacks and she only seems to use quick attacks which makes it almost impossible.

Comment: Hi Josh, welcome to Arqade! I anticipate there's some helpful information in here, but it's very difficult to read. Could you help clarify your answer by doing a grammar pass on it?